# Does is exist event before slide change?

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I search in code event that emit before slide changing, but nothing. Does anybody know how can I run my callback before slide start changing?

Comment: specify swiper version

Answer (score 0):

In the current version onSlideChangeStart seems to be what you are looking for